# Centos ip forwarding getting UNKOWN HOST

Tags: linux, centos, networking, nat

I have a simple configuration, containing a two CentOS VMs. First one (VM1) has INTERNET access through eth0 and an internal network with VM2 on eth1.

```
ping from VM1 to www.google.com -> works
ping from VM1 to VM2(172.16.73.34) -> works
ping from VM2 to VM1(712.16.73.33) -> works
ping from VM2 to eth0 on VM1 (192.167.0.101) -> works
ping from VM2 to www.google.com -> 'UNKOWN HOST'
```

I want to be able to access the internet from VM2.

```
VM1 configurations:
 default gateway: 192.168.0.1
 eth0:
    inet addr: 192.168.0.101
    mask: 255.255.255.0
 eth1:
    inet addr: 172.16.73.33
    mask: 255.255.255.224
 resolv.conf:
    nameserver: 213.154.124.1
    nameserver: 193.231.252.1
```

-

```
VM2 configurations:
 default gateway: 172.16.73.33
 eth1: 
    inet addr: 172.16.73.34
    mask: 255.255.255.224
 resolv.conf:
    nameserver: 213.154.124.1
    nameserver: 193.231.252.1
```

I've added some rules to IPTABLES following some tutorial:

```
/sbin/iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -F INPUT 
/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -F OUTPUT 
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD DROP
/sbin/iptables -F FORWARD 
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
/sbin/service iptables restart
```

Also, in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, I have `net.ipv4.ip_forwarding = 1.`

What am I missing in order to be able to ping to www.google.com from VM2?

Answer (score 0):

You are masquerading the wrong interface. It should be as follows.

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```